# No matching function for call, using a function pointer

Tags: c++

```
#include <TestAssert.h>

...

if (TestAssert::Equals(10, "x", 10, "y", 10, f_TestFailedMsg, v_TCResult, 
 s_TestCaseCtrl)) { return; }
```

Declaration of f_TestFailedMsg (in base class):

```
void A_AbstractTestStub_Actor::f_TestFailedMsg( const char * 
 apc_FormatString, ... )
{
```

Parts of TestAssert.h (dedfinition of Test_failed_callback_function and Equals):

```
typedef void (*Test_failed_callback_function)(T_String);

static bool Equals( int lineNumber, T_String valueText, int value, T_String 
 expectedText, int expected, Test_failed_callback_function testFailedMsg, 
 bool & tcResult, P_testCaseCtrl::Base & testCaseCtrl );
```

Implementation of Equals (TestAssert.cpp):

```
bool TestAssert::Equals( int lineNumber, T_String valueText, int value, 
 T_String expectedText, int expected, Test_failed_callback_function 
 testFailedMsg, bool & tcResult, P_testCaseCtrl::Base & testCaseCtrl )
{
    ...
```

I get the error:

```
no matching function for call to 'TestAssert::Equals(int const char [29], 
 int&, const char[4], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>, bool&, 
 P_testCaseCtrl::Base&)
Tester.cpp:181:89: note: candidate is:
 ../TestAssert.h:30:17: note: static bool TestAssert::Equals(int, T_String, 
 int, T_String, int, Test_failed_callback_function, bool&, 
 P_testCaseCtrl::Base&)

../TestAssert.h:30:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 6 
 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' 
 to 'Test_failed_callback_function {aka void (*)(std::basic_string<char>)}'
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f_TestFailedMsg` is a non-static member function; it requires an object of type `A_AbstractTestStub_Actor` to be called on. It cannot bind to a `void (*)(T_String)`.

There are a few ways to solve this issue. If `f_TestFailedMsg` shouldn't require an object, make it static.

If you want to supply the member function as an argument and get an object to call it on later, you could change your `Test_failed_callback_function` to be a member function pointer:

```
typedef void (A_AbstractTestStub_Actor::*Test_failed_callback_function)(T_String)
```

Obviously this will restrict the function to being a member of `A_AbstractTestStub_Actor`, but you can do some template magic to accept members of other types.

The most expressive option if C++11 is available to you is to make `Test_failed_callback_function` a `std::function<void(T_String)>`, then bind an object with a lambda or `std::bind`:

```
if (TestAssert::Equals(10, "x", 10, "y", 10, 
                       [&my_obj](T_String s){my_obj.f_TestFailedMsg(s);},
                       v_TCResult, s_TestCaseCtrl)) 
{ return; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... it gives me the insight of the problem and decided instead to pass the complete object since I need more items, and call the function directly from the passed object instead.